# Asymptotic Approximation for the Laplace Transform as $x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion, approximation

I'm trying to figure out the Asymptotic Approximation for the Laplace Transform but I am stuck at finding the order of the Remainder.

The transform is: $F(x) = \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-xt}f(t){\rm d}t, x>0$

Using repeated integration by parts, I showed that:
$$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{x^{n+1}} + R_N(x)$$

where:
$$R_N(x) = \frac{1}{x^{N+1}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xt}f^{(N+1)}(t){\rm d}t$$

Now I need to show that: $R_N(x) = O(x^{-(N+2)})$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. I am trying to use the formula from my notes:

$$|R_N(x)| \leq \frac{|x|^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}\sup{|f^{(N+1)}(t)|}$$

but to be honest, I don't really understand what happens in this formula and especially how to apply here.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: You are mixing up the remainder of the Taylor series of $f$ and the remainder after repeated integration by parts. They are totally differet things.

Comment: @Gary ok I see, so if my formula for the Remainder is wrong, how can I determine it?

Comment: Note that $$
\left| {R_N (x)} \right| \le \frac{1}{{x^{N + 1} }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - xt} \mathop {\sup }\limits_{t > 0} \left| {f^{(N + 1)} (t)} \right|{\rm d}t}  = \mathop {\sup }\limits_{t > 0} \left| {f^{(N + 1)} (t)} \right|\frac{1}{{x^{N + 2} }}
$$ for $x>0$, which is what you want, provided that the sup is finite.

Comment: @Gary I think I remember this, do you have a name for this formula/method?

Comment: Note that if you have $\left| {f^{(N + 1)} (t)} \right| \le M_N {\rm e}^{at} $ with some $M_N>0$, $a>0$ for all $t>0$, then $$
\left| {R_N (x)} \right| \le \frac{{M_N }}{{x^{N + 1} (x - a)}} = \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^{N + 2} }}} \right)
$$ where the first inequality holds for $x>a$. I am not aware of any specific names for these, they are just straightforward estimates.

Comment: @Gary, thank you for the advice, I managed to get the results!